# Apache DNS forwarding is finally working but some domains are resolving to the VPS IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain

I have a Linode VPS and 1&1 has my domains. I've finally got all of my web addresses pointing to my server and displaying the proper content but only one of my three domains is keeping its web address in the address bar; the other 2 are resolving to an IP address (so I put in example.com and it displays the right content but switches to x.x.x.x).

The one that is working is a subdomain, if that matters (foo.example.com). What would cause this to happen. I'm not sure at what stage this is all breaking down.

I have 1&1 pointing the DNS to the Linode DNS servers (ns1.linode.com, ns2.linode.com, etc) and I've set them up with Linode's DNS manager. I also have configs in my apache sites-available/sites-enabled for all three.

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks. I can provide more info if required.

Comment: Post one of the domains in question. That will make troubleshooting much easier.

Comment: If the address bar is changing, then a redirect is occurring.  Are there any redirects configured in Apache?  What content is running within Apache?  Web application code often generates redirects as well.

Comment: My bet is on URL redirection by 1&1.

Comment: Do you think maybe 1&1 hasn't propogated the name server pointers on my other domains yet?

Comment: From where I am it appears to work... Have you been able to fix your problem?